# Converting canvas image from webpage to SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, canvas

I'd like to grab the QR code from my Instagram page, which is only available for download as png and convert it to SVG. Is there a way to accomplish this? The only code I have to work with on the page is the canvas element with CSS classes:

```
<canvas class="x1xux3cy xc6p2dh" width="235" height="270"></canvas>
```

Comment: Canvas is a raster format, SVG is vector so not really.

Comment: Do you need a programmatic way of doing this? Which language?

Comment: @Kaiido I was thinking of using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A QR code (typically) contains/encodes a **link**. So you just need to decode your **raster** QR code to obtain this link, then create a new **vector** QR code containing it. The new QR code might not look exactly the same, but it will point to the same destination, which I presume is all you actually need.

1. To decode your QR code to a link, use your phone camera or a web-based decoder like [this](https://app.bytescout.com/qr-code-reader/qr-code-reader.html).
2. To create a new QR code from a link and save it as SVG, use a free web-based generator like [this](https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/).